# How can I access music files in iOS?

Tags: ios, filesystems, apple-music, apple-musickit

I have a question about accessing files in iOS programming.

I want to access music files in iOS, and I searched about these topics but I didn't find proper documents.

Could you recommend proper materials about **accessing music files**?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MusicKit API to integrate apple music inside your app.

MusicKit :- 
https://developer.apple.com/musickit/

MusicKit WWDC Introduction:-
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/502/

MusicKit integration tutorial:- 
https://crunchybagel.com/integrating-apple-music-into-your-ios-app/

Comment: Thanks, but I want to access music files in iOS device, not music files from remote server. MusicKit API looks for accessing music files from remote server.